# How to remove items from menu in netBeans platform?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I have module application. When I run it, the main window of that app has quite complex menu.
How to remove some items from menu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove menu items from the menu bar by adding entries to your project's layer.xml file.

You should read through ['Tweaking the User Interface' from the 'NetBeans Platform HTML Editor' tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-htmleditor.html#tweakingthemenuitems) to get a rough idea of what you will need to do.

There is [another tutorial-ish description of using the layer file to hide items](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-idioms.html), too.

Comment: The first item is good for removing items (the question asked), but leaves a decent leap for adding them (what I was looking for).  In any case, I found this helpful.

Comment: I think the section on tweaking the menu has been removed from the first linked document

Answer (score 3):

In netbeans 8.0 , the layer file is generated when ever a module contains 'configuration type' annonations in java code, for example a module with top component. The generated layer.xml is located at build directory classes/META-INF/generated-layer.xml. However, the generated-layer.xml is not editable. To hide/show menubar / tool bar, click on the module, click other and add XML layer file. Now under the important files you can see XML layer. Expand it. Now expand  . Expand the "Menu Bar". Delete the menu bar which you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way appears to be, as Martin Krauskopf wrote:

Just go to:

*Projects view (Ctrl-1)* **>>** *your module* **>>** *Important Files* **>>** *XML Layer* **>>**  *Menu Bar* **>>** *Help*

and delete what you want (it will actually generate appropriate content in layer.xml of the module).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it in layer.xml

layer in context
- Menu Bar

here's the link

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-htmleditor.html