# NetBeans Platform Main Frame

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am looking into the `NetBeans platform` for developing desktop applications. I am a complete newbie in it. I understood till now the module architecture. Now I want to do some `GUI` work. My question is very simple and feel embarrassed to ask it, but how can I edit the main frame of the application? I mean the one generated automatically by `NetBeans`. I looked around but for god's sake, I can't see it in the `IDE`:(

Edit: It seems there is a misunderstanding.  I know how to create a JFrame:) I am talking about the `NetBeans platform`, when your application is built on top of the NetBeans core. [Here](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbSep2005.html) is a short article. At the bottom there are two screenshots. The IDE generates a Main frame looking like the real NetBeans IDE. I can create new modules and so on. But I want to edit this Main frame, but I don't see it in the IDE. Hope my question is clear now.

Thanks in advance:)

Regards,
Petar

Comment: Oh! Yes I see. Well I don't know anything of creating modules in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned more things of the `NetBeans platform`, I understood that there is a virtual `FileSystem` which is build from combining `layer.xml` files from all modules. This `FileSystem` is the configuration of the application. It includes things as which menu items to be shown on the main frame, etc. So I guess the main frame is edited this way:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is like Petar says, but to be more specific, one way to do this is from the Netbeans GUI is described here. http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/70/nbm-htmleditor.html#tweakingthemenuitems. This is for 7.0 version of netbeans.

I found useful this question also [How to remove items from menu in netBeans platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435153/how-to-remove-items-from-menu-in-netbeans-platform).