# Hide Menu items from Netbeans Platform Application in Maven

Tags: maven, customization, netbeans-platform

This is related to [How do I hide menus without a layer file in NetBeans Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282081/how-do-i-hide-menus-without-a-layer-file-in-netbeans-platform) and [How to remove items from menu in netBeans platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435153/how-to-remove-items-from-menu-in-netbeans-platform). Sadly those are related to an ant built platform.

I'm trying to find out how to the same in Maven built application. I bet there's a way to add a custom layer file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works the same way even if you have a Maven-based NetBeans platform application.  Try right clicking the module of interest and selecting New->Other->Module Development->XML Layer.  This will create and register the layer.xml for you, which you can then hack as desired.